# Wrong number of arguments in VBA (MS Access) with SOAP request created through wsl.exe

Tags: vba, ms-access, soap, wsdl

I've created a C# dll using the web service wsdl.exe. Based on that I have create both a C# and VB.Net application, and they both retrieve the data I expect and give me the result.

The VBA code that calls the same external dll fails. The dll returns an object that has a property 'DataArea' that is an array of objects.

```
Dim response As CustomerPrice.SimulatePriceResponseType
Set response = New CustomerPrice.SimulatePriceResponseType
Set response = CustPriceService.SimulatePrice(st)
Dim bob As String
bob = response.DataArea(0).bookPrice_Value
```

In C# and VB.Net the last line gives the value required.
In VBA the last line indicates a 'Wrong Number of arguments or invalid property assignment'
In 'Immediate mode debugging'

- Print response gives SimulatePriceResponseType as expected.
- Print response.DataArea gives Type Mismatch (error 13)
- Print response.DataArea(0) gives wrong number of arguments (error 450)

Any ideas what is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You don't show in either snip where you set/created the var "response".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has something to do with the array, or with how VBA is interpreting it, although I am not sure exactly what.

I found the dll source code and added a property that returned only the first element of the array as an PriceData object, not an PriceData[] array.

Works as it should